# JSF component loses CSS style after AJAX render call

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I have a big complex form with validation on most of the fields. Somewhere I have `<h:selectOneMenu>` where if I select a certain value, I want another `<h:selectOneMenu>` to appear under it. The second list is initially invisible (I set it with `rerender` property to `false` and I make it true with `clickListener()` function and render it an ajax call).

```
<o:form>
    <h:panelGroup  id="group" > 
        <label>Status</label>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="status" immediate="true" label="Status" value="#{candidateBean.statusVO}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" required="true" requiredMessage="The field is empty">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{settingsBean.settings.statusListVO.statusVO}" var="status" itemValue="#{status}" itemLabel="#{status.name}"/>
            <f:ajax  event="valueChange" listener="#{candidateBean.clickListener}" execute="form"  render="group"  />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:messages for="status" style="color:red" />                  

        <label>Invalidation Reason</label>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="invalidationReason" rendered="#{candidateBean.falseTest}" label="Invalidation Reason" value="#{candidateBean.invalidationReasonVO}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" requiredMessage="The field is empty">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{settingsBean.settings.invalidationReasonListVO.invalidationReasonVO}" var="invalidation" itemValue="#{invalidation}" itemLabel="#{invalidation.name}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>                      

    </h:panelGroup>
</o:form>
```

I used `<o:form>` instead of `<h:form>` because somewhere in the form I used `<o:ignoreValidationFailed>` because I needed to update a dataTable with values from a `<h:selectOneMenu>` and force update on my model.

Everything works except when I select a value from the list, the elements inside the panelGroup are rendered without any style at all and I can't figure out why. If I refresh the page the CSS is loaded on the elements but this is not an option.

My bean is `@SessionScoped`.

Comment: The css style. It renders in the default html style without any css at all and it is very ugly. I don't know if it is related to omnifaces but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: I don't realy know because I only continued this project I didn't start it by myself but I don't use PrimeFaces Mobile. I think it uses bootstrap

Comment: I did that. I gave styleClass to both selectonemenu and it didn't work. The strange thing is that I have multiple ayax render calls on the form on some tables that I populate from lists but there I don't have any problemss

Comment: This question is not in detail answerable without a clear MCVE. At least, the problem is not in OmniFaces, but it can offer a solution to that.

Comment: The project is prety big.. I will return monday with more details. I'm sorry I didn't explan better and thx a lot :)